# Merge and export Excel/Word/PDF to PDF

Tags: c#, .net, excel, pdf, pdf-generation

I have **multiple** documents *(document types varies between Word, Excel and PDF)*

The best scenario is if i could find a library that can **merge all document** and **export as PDF**.

There are three libraries i have looked at, but i can't seem to find one that handles all document types:

- [ABCPDF](https://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.aspx)
- [iTextSharp](http://itextpdf.com/)
- [PixEdit](https://www.pixedit.com/en)

I don't wish to mix and match libraries for PDF conversion.

However - i don't mind using one library for conversion, and a separate for merge/export.

I saw some other post discussing word -> PDF, and [Spire](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Spire.PDF/) was mentioned.

> Question: Does one of my findings actually support all of this, or can
>   someone recommend something better? Needs to be .NET supported

Comment: You can check [GemBox](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/) components, they can accomplish your task. GemBox.Document can convert Word to PDF, GemBox.Spreadsheet can convert Excel to PDF and GemBox.Pdf can merge multiple PDF files into a single PDF.

Comment: Spire.Office allows merging multiple types of files like word, excel, pdf, powerpoint to 1 pdf file: https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.PDF/Spire.PDF-Program-Guide/Document-Operation/Merge-Multiple-File-Types-into-One-PDF-in-C-VB.NET.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use GroupDocs.Merger for .NET [API](https://downloads.groupdocs.com/merger/net) to merge Word, Excel, Presentation and PDF files. Have a look at the following code:

```
using (Merger merger = new Merger(@"c:\document1.pdf"))
{
    merger.Join(@"c:\document2.doc");
    merger.Join(@"c:\document3.ppt");
    merger.Join(@"c:\document4.xls");
    merger.Save(@"c:\merged.pdf");
}
```

*Disclosure: I work as a developer evangelist at GroupDocs.*